# Porting fork-exec idiom to Windows

Tags: linux, cross-platform, io-redirection, child-process, mingw-w64

`fork()` is a nasty libc function to implement on Win32. Fortunately Win32 `CreateProcess()` is rather close to `fork()` followed by `exec()`.

It seems there are many different system calls for process spawning on Linux these days.

The quesion is: how do I make fork+exec portable and use CreateProcess() on Windows?

So on Unix it does something like this (cross `chroot`/`chdir` of course):

https://github.com/mindcat/pacman/blob/master/lib/libalpm/util.c#L529

And on Windows it does something like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Are there any existing wrappers?

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider using some cross-platform libraries like [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (with [spawning process](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) facilities), Qt with [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html), [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), [boost process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/), etc etc.... ?

Then you could (in principle) write source code which runs both on Windows and on Linux.

<sup>(you don't "port" `fork`+ `exec` to Windows, you only use higher level constructs provided by such libraries to create new processes).</sup>